# Polyhedral embedding from graph degree sequence

Tags: ds.algorithms, co.combinatorics, topological-graph-theory

**Given**: A degree sequence.

**Wanted**: A graph and a polyhedral embedding of this graph (described by a rotation system or something equivalent). By polyhedral embedding I mean only the combinatorial concept. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_system).

Is there a fast way to do this? I tried a backtracking approach, adding edges one at a time, but it is too slow. It becomes intractable for a 3-regular graph of 30 vertices.